# To migrate my aws ec2 instance to digital Ocean droplet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, digital-ocean

I want to create an image of my ec2 and transfer image to digital Ocean and create a droplet out of image. Is it possible? if yes, How do I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you ask at: https://www.reddit.com/r/digital_ocean/

Answer (score 1):

DigitalOcean supports custom images. You can check the requirements here: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/images/custom-images/#image-requirements